# Switching from GridView to ListView when Windows Store app is snapped

Tags: javascript, listview, windows-8, winjs

I am trying to change the layout of my listView control from "GridView" to "ListView" when application gets snapped. Of course, it should return to "GridView" in any other state. I wrote some code, but it doesn't work, so I wonder why...

This is the code I've written:

```
var viewState = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView;
var list = document.getElementById("messageDisplay").winControl;
if (viewState == Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.snapped) {
    list.layout = new WinJS.UI.ListLayout();
}
else
{
    list.layout = new WinJS.UI.GridLayout();
}
```

Comment: Is the code defined in the "updateLayout" function in the page's js file?  If so, one of the parameters passed is viewState.  Also, it would seem that you could handle this with Media Queries instead, just a thought.

Comment: share code that initializes the listview other properties like itemDataSource, groupDataSource, itemTemplate, groupHeaderTemplate, and updateLayout method.

Comment: FWIW: We've had problems getting this to work as well just from styling perspective of handling both situations -- it made it very confusing. We ended up just having two lists in some situations, one that shows when snapped, and one that shows when not, mind you that these were lists with static datasources though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150600.aspx) simply listen for the resize event and make the changes to your listview's layout property.

I can't tell wher ein your code you are calling the similar code, so here is the entire method you'll need

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function (e) {
    var currentViewState = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value;
    var snapped = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.snapped;

    if (currentViewState === snapped) {
        that.listView.layout = new WinJS.UI.ListLayout(); 
    }
    else if (lastViewState === snapped && currentViewState !== snapped) {
        that.listView.layout = new WinJS.UI.GridLayout();
    }

    lastViewState = currentViewState;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking list.forceLayout() it saved my life many times... ;-)

Comment: forceLayout is only when data potentially changes I believe. For static data simply use resize.